# How to fast travel when not in the Batcave?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

In *Batman: Arkham Origins*, you can fast travel by using your Batwing while in the Batcave, but how do you fast travel when *not* in the Batcave?

I tried going to one of the fast travel locations, but I can't see anything that'd allow me to summon the Batwing for fast travelling.

Comment: You could be a real Batman and just grapple yourself through the city..

Comment: Yeah, but Alfred keeps pestering me about not getting enough sleep, but how am I supposed to find the time to sleep, if I spend the whole night grappling around the city?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to restore the Comms Tower of the district you want to be able to fast travel to.  Doing so will unlock the Batwing Drop Point to that area.  You can tell if it is unlocked if the icon is white (as opposed to being red).

[image: Coventry Batwing drop point]

To fast travel to the location, hover over the drop point icon and choose fast travel option.  I play the PC version so that would be <kbd>Enter</kbd> (by default).  For the other consoles, that would be <kbd>A</kbd> on the Xbox 360 and <kbd>X</kbd> on the PlayStation 3.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the "Fast Travel" option that pops up. How stupid of me... Thanks for the answer.